# CSS drop cap displays differently in Firefox and Safari. How do I adjust for this?

Tags: firefox, browser, compatibility

I'm struggling to find the right combination of CSS to help ensure my drop cap on my blog posts display the same in all browsers. I primarily use Safari and do my design work there. How it renders in Safari is my preference.

In Firefox, the drop cap hangs low and the text doesn't wrap around the letter. I added a negative bottom margin and now the text wraps. But it is still hanging too low. I really want this consistent.

What can I do to remedy this? Thank you.

[This is my website here.](http://www.moosenotes.com)

Answer (score 0):

Create Drop Cap : Float the first character of the para to the left.

```css
.firstcharacter {
  float: left;
  color: #903;
  font-size: 75px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  font-family: Georgia;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="firstcharacter">L</span> orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tristique lobortis orci ac lacinia. Fusce eu purus eget diam vehicula auctor nec eu elit. Morbi consequat facilisis orci vel malesuada. Donec ultrices
  molestie sollicitudin. Aliquam pharetra libero enim. Donec et suscipit massa. Donec dui odio, dignissim non sodales et, tincidunt a sapien. Phasellus elit nibh, adipiscing sed blandit vel, interdum et arcu.
</p>
```